# Regarding a Conditional Distribution (Please Check for Me)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I just want to have certain that I'm thinking right

If
$$f(x,y)=\frac{12}{5}\times x\times (2-x-y)$$for  $0<x<1, 0<y<1$ and $f(x,y)=0$ c.c.
the conditional distribution of X  if $0<y<\frac{1}{2}$.
$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=\frac{\frac{12}{5}\times x\times (2-x-y)}{\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{12}{5}\times x\times (2-x-y)dy}$$

Comment: The formula for the probability density function of the marginal distribution $Y$ is $f_Y(y)= \int f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx$ over the support of the random variable $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the conditional distribution of X,  if $0<y<\frac{1}{2}\text{ should be something like below:}$
$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=\frac{\frac{12}{5}\times x\times (2-x-y)}{\int_{y=0}^{y=\frac{1}{2}}\int_{x=0}^{{x=1}}\frac{12}{5}\times x\times (2-x-y)dxdy}$$